# PySide: how to clean `QLineEdit` field with a button click?

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, grid-layout, qlineedit

I am trying to make a simple app with PySide. I have a grid layout with some cells being `QLineEdit` widgets. I want to clear the text fields of the 4 of these by a button click. Here is a part of my code:

```
editFields = [angle1Edit, angle2Edit, len1Edit, len2Edit]

clearBtn.clicked.connect(self.clearAll(editFields))

def clearAll(self, fields):
    for field in fields:
        return field.clear
```

In the `editFields` I collected the 4 widgets which I want to clean. But this only clears the first one but not all of them.

How can I do it for all? Is there another possibility to perform such action? Maybe I can use other widget for this task? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think you want [`field.clear()`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QLineEdit.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QLineEdit.clear) as `field.clear` will just give the clear function. Secondly, `QLineEdit.clear()` doesn't return anything so just:

```
for field in fields:
    field.clear()
```

Is needed as opposed to

```
for field in fields:
    return field.clear()
```

Lastly, [`QAbstractButton.clicked` is probably trying to pass the `checked`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractButton.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractButton.clicked) argument which is causing issues, and might be forcing it to get the `editFields[false]` field, aka the `editFields[0]` field which is the first.

So, in conclusion, I'd make the editFields belong to what ever holds the fields and button, and try this and see if it gives the results you need:

```
self.editFields = [angle1Edit, angle2Edit, len1Edit, len2Edit]

clearBtn.clicked.connect(self.clearAll)

def clearAll(self, checked=False):
    for field in self.editFields:
        field.clear()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It gives me an error `<self> object has no attribute "editFields"`. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: `for field in editFields: clearBtn.clicked.connect(field.clear)`.